Unable to access wordpress admin page due to adding https to url
I’m unable to access the WordPress admin page because the URL keeps automatically switching from HTTP to HTTPS whenever I try to enter it.
WHAT I TRIED
I was adjusting the settings on my website and mistakenly added HTTPS to the URL, even though I don't have an SSL certificate.
WHAT I EXPECTED TO HAPPEN
I expected it to reject the change and display an error due to the missing SSL certificate.
WHAT ACTUALLY HAPPENED
I can't access the WordPress admin page because it keeps looking for an SSL certificate that doesn't exist. Additionally, it automatically redirects HTTP to HTTPS, which is causing further issues since the URL is incorrect.

I am not sure if this can help but if you can access your database and the wp_options table, maybe there you can change back your siteurl where the url of your website is stored to http and not https

You can set the WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME constants in wp-config.php file with http to override the database settings.
